# Using hVPlot and the plots won't overlay even though they should, is data frame size an issue?

Tags: python, graphics, overlay, interactive, hvplot

Unable to create an overlay plot with both curve lines and interact with them both on the same curve. What am I doing wrong? The exp line has more data points than the exp2 line as that was a theoretical line I hard-coded in.

This is my code:

```
theoreticaly = [20]*420 + [i for i in reversed(np.linspace(-40, 20, 600))]+[-40]*600 + [i for i in np.linspace(-40,40,840)]+[40]*1000
theoreticalx = [i for i in range(0,3460)]

names = {'theoreticalx': theoreticalx, 'theoreticaly': theoreticaly}
part = pd.DataFrame(names)
     
# saving the dataframe to csv
part.to_csv('datatheo.csv', index=False)

#reading in the csv file
readingtheo = pd.read_csv("datatheo.csv")
#Defining the time based on 2895 records and data frequency of 0.4s 
t=[]
for val in df["Time"].tolist():
    nums = re.split(r"[:\s]", val)
    t.append(3600*int(nums[1]) + 60*int(nums[2]) + int(nums[3]) + int(nums[4])/1000)
    time = np.array(t)
    time = time - time[0]
    
avg = [(topt1[j] + topt2[j])/2 for j in range(len(time))]


#make dataframe with both new columns

xcel = {'time': time, 'avg': avg}
final = pd.DataFrame(xcel)
     
# saving the dataframe to csv
final.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)

#reading in the csv file
reading = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Plotting the temperatures
exp = reading.hvplot(x='time',y='avg',value_label ='Thermocouple Average',legend = 'right', title = 'Temperature in OTS Top chamber + °C/min',xlabel='Time (s)', ylabel='Temperature (deg C)',line_color ='green')
exp2 = readingtheo.hvplot(x = 'theoreticalx',y = 'theoreticaly',value_label= "Theoretical Pattern Curve",legend = 'right', title = 'Temperature in OTS Top chamber + °C/min',xlabel='Time (s)', ylabel='Temperature (deg C)')
finalplot = (exp+exp2).cols(1)
hvplot.show(finalplot)
```

The plots just refuse to overlay I tried the holoview option too with .cols(1) it still didn't work.